# Sometimes my Notification not shows

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alarms

Why does my Notification sometimes not showing?

I create `setRecurringAlarm(this);` in MainActivity and I would like to use this code to show the notification every 30 minutes

This is my code:

```
private void setRecurringAlarm(Context context) {
    Log.d("MyService", "setRecurringAlarm() activated...");
        Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        updateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        Intent downloader = new Intent(context, MyStartServiceReceiver.class);
        downloader.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, downloader, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pendingIntent);
   }
```

And this is my MyStartServiceReceiver :

```
public class MyStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
       @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent dailyUpdater = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(dailyUpdater);
        Log.d("AlarmReceiver", "Called context.startService from AlarmReceiver.onReceive");
       }
    }
```

This is my MyService :

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
    public MyService() {
       super("MyServiceName");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("MyService", "Execute MyTask");
        new MyTask().execute();
        this.sendNotification(this);
    }
    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
         protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
               Log.d("MyService", "Calling doInBackground() in MyTask");
               return false;
        }
    }        
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private void sendNotification(Context context) {
        Log.d("MyService", "Execute sendNotification()");
        // here is my notification code --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558619/how-to-set-notification-to-clear-itself-on-click  

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using wakelock in your `IntentService`. There is no gaurantee that your phone will be awake because BroadcastReciever will return immediately. You need to have wakelock in your `IntentService`

Check this out

[AlarmManager.setRepeating - Service does not seem to repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658775/alarmmanager-setrepeating-service-does-not-seem-to-repeat)